# Changing Frame in Collection View's cellForItemAtIndexPath Method

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to IOS.

I have used collection view. I am using Prototype cell in it. I have not used Auto-Layout in my app.

I need to change frame of buttons and view in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. But when I first scroll to move to next cell it not reflecting first time. I can only see blank with out any buttons or view. I have checked all the frames are correctly updating. Still I can not see any thing.

Though if I again go to previous call and come back it will seen properly.

Please find below code of `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
     Feed *feed;
    NSMutableAttributedString * string;

    feed = [arrTop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ShuffleCell *myCell = [collectionView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ShuffleCell"
                         forIndexPath:indexPath];

    myCell.index = indexPath;


    myCell.delegate = self;


   // Below frame changes are not working


        myCell.vwBack.frame = collect.frame;
        myCell.imgShare.frame = CGRectMake(myCell.imgShare.frame.origin.x, myCell.imgShare.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.width );
        myCell.lblText.center = CGPointMake(myCell.imgShare.frame.size.width / 2, myCell.imgShare.frame.size.height / 2);
        myCell.lblText.frame = CGRectMake(20
                                          , myCell.imgShare.frame.origin.y + 20, self.view.frame.size.width - 20,self.view.frame.size.width -20);

        int totHeight = (collect.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.width);
        myCell.vwBtn.frame = CGRectMake(myCell.vwBtn.frame.origin.x, collect.frame.size.height -totHeight, myCell.vwBtn.frame.size.width, totHeight);
        [myCell.vwBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(myCell.vwBtn.frame.origin.x, collect.frame.size.height -totHeight, myCell.vwBtn.frame.size.width, totHeight)];
        myCell.btnFavoriteBack.frame = CGRectMake(myCell.btnFavoriteBack.frame.origin.x, 0, myCell.btnFavoriteBack.frame.size.width, totHeight/3);
        [myCell.btnFavoriteBack setFrame:CGRectMake(myCell.btnFavoriteBack.frame.origin.x, 0, myCell.btnFavoriteBack.frame.size.width, totHeight/3)];
        myCell.btnShare.frame = CGRectMake(myCell.btnShare.frame.origin.x, (totHeight/3), myCell.btnShare.frame.size.width, totHeight/3);
        myCell.btnReport.frame = CGRectMake(myCell.btnReport.frame.origin.x, (totHeight/3)*2, myCell.btnReport.frame.size.width, totHeight/3);
        myCell.vwLikeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 82, (totHeight/3 - 32)/2, 82,32);

        NSLog(@"Y :- %f",myCell.vwBtn.frame.size.height);





    return myCell;
```

I have also attached screen shot of same.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: Add a line [cell setNeedsLayout] before you return the cell and see what happens.

Comment: @gabbler Thanks for help. But still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line should fix the problem. Let the subviews of cell translate their frames to constraints.

```
cell.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Comment: Do I need to write this line for all the subviews whose frame I want to change ?

Comment: Yes, possibly you have to.

Comment: it's not working. The strange is that it runs perfectly if go to previous cell and come back again.

Comment: Is auto layout turned on in storyboard?

Comment: No,auto layout is not turned on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64539/discussion-between-impossible-and-gabbler).